# Is it possible to turn off a specific USB port so it doesn't accept any device?

Tags: usb

I have a lot of ports on my computer. I would like to turn off one of them, so when I connect my phone to that port, it only charges. I do want my phone to work with my computer in some occasions though, so I hope other ports are not affected.

I would just like to know how possible this is.

Comment: Possible.. But some hacks are needed to do this..

Comment: Hardware solution: Buy a male to female USB plug and cut/isolate/remove the center lines.

Comment: @Helio Then why do not I just buy a USB power station...?

Comment: You can purchase USB cables that provide charge only. The data leads aren't wired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [plug & play](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QRRZ2QM) (literally) option:

[image: charge only usb dongle]

It's a good idea if you want to avoid pop-up messages and file browsers every time you plug your phone in for charging only.

This is also more fool-proof than the software approach because software that turns off the port for data can be reversed by software that turns it back on. Or it might be reinitialized during suspend/resume or some other process you didn't foresee.

Answer (score 6):

First, run `lsusb`.

The output should be like:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1020  
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0bc2:a013 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:219c Broadcom Corp.
```

In the output, find the device number of the port to be disabled. For example, the Seagate drive in the example has `Device 009` - that is its device number. Then the id will be `usb[device number]` - such as `usb9`

Then, disable USB wake-up (do this only once):

**Be sure to replace `X` in `usbX` with the device number.**

```
echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/wakeup
```

Then turn it off:

```
echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level
```

#### Undo this:

```
echo enabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/wakeup
echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level
```

Comment: Attempted the above commands and returned... `tee: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb11/power/wakeup: No such file or directory
disabled`

Comment: found very helpful information in this thread [USB Port Power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux)

Comment: I get `tee: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level: Invalid argument` when `echo suspend`, while `echo on` no such error.

Comment: @林果皞 Did you replace the `X` in `usbX`?

Comment: @UniversallyUniqueID Yes, I replace the real id with 'X' before write the previous comment, or else my error message would be `No such file or directory` instead. My distro is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: correct answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057384/disable-usb-port

Comment: Looks like the `write error: Invalid argument` is because the `suspend` option is no longer supported, since kernel 2.6.32. See https://superuser.com/a/371254.

Answer (score -1):

I cut a piece of tape to fit the inner two data pins, and pushed it into place with a toothpick.

This is on my phone charging base so I shouldn't have to redo this tape job.

No more annoying popups, which were getting ridiculous. The last time I plugged in my phone I got 9 different popup windows, all of which had different error messages.