# Disable usb port

Tags: usb, udev, modprobe

I want my computer to stop listening on a specific usb port. The problem is that the device connected there keeps disconnecting and reconnecting. I think this may be due to a hardware fault. The usb device is a touch screen. With the `watch` command I can verify that it keeps appearing and disappearing.

I've tried both blocking the kernel modules with `modprobe` and blocking the specific USB device with `udev`. Alas nothing seems to do the trick. What other options do I have?

For reference:

```
> cat /lib/udev/rules.d/20-block-elan.rules
# ELAN Touchscreen
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0125", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Comment: i like how on this question there's a "closed because duplicate", linking to another thread that says in a comment "correct answer over there" linking to this thread, and neither answer actually achieves what was asked, because the power management works through the *device* driver, not the specific port...

Answer (score 3):

You can disable specific usb ports.
First see which devices are available:

```
for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device;cat $device;done
```

Which will give you a list of your connected devices for example:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-14/product
Logitech G430 Headset
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/product
Razer DeathAdder Elite
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/product
Keyboard G910
/sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/product
USB 10/100/1000 LAN
```

If I would want to disable my mouse (Razer DeathAdder Elite from the List above) I would type:

```
echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/level
```

And if I would want to turn it on again:

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/level
```

Comment: when I used the first tee command u mentioned, it threw me this error: :Invalid argument". As u can see the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/sNSksJo

Comment: Looks like the `write error: Invalid argument` is because this option is no longer supported, since kernel 2.6.32. See https://superuser.com/a/371254.