# USB power only on specific device/port?

Tags: usb, power-management, battery

I've searched about this for hours, no dice. I have a wireless headset (Creative SXFI Air) that can be used with a USB cable. The headset allows charging while it's being used simultaneously with a USB cable.

According to the manufacturer's website:

> SXFI AIR will start charging automatically when connected via USB to a power source EXCEPT in USB/Mass Storage Mode.

Apparently Windows doesn't treat it as a USB Mass Storage Device since it charges normally while it's in use, but Linux does, since it draws from battery and charges only when it's powered off. I do not want to disable the USB port entirely.

Here's the output of **lsusb**:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 18f8:0f97 [Maxxter] Optical Gaming Mouse [Xtrem]
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 041e:3258 Creative Technology, Ltd Creative SXFI AIR
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Bus 003 Device 009: ID 041e:3258 Creative Technology, Ltd Creative SXFI AIR**

Is there any way to make Linux treat this device as a "power only" device, or make that specific USB port do power delivery only? Please, only provide solutions that can be done in software.

Comment: Here are 2 that loop to each other about doing something similar:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/741760/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-a-specific-usb-port-so-it-doesnt-accept-any-device  and  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057384/disable-usb-port  I would think that it would be much easier just to have a USB no-data cable that is missing a wire in the connector that is used for sensing when the device is plugged in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Terrance. Please understand that I seek software solutions and not hardware ones. I've read and tried the solutions you linked; none of them work. If it can be done in Windows, I'm sure it can be done in Linux, too.

Comment: That is why I gave you 2 links.  They contain software solutions that may work.

Comment: I appreciate it but unfortunately they didn't do it for me. :( Any ideas?

Comment: Just look around is all I can say and hopefully you can find something that works for you. Another possibility one where OP stated that there were able to disable it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047959/how-to-disable-a-specific-usb-port-permanently-in-linux  Different hardware can react differently to the commands.

Comment: Still nothing... I've searched for hours and hours. I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Did youtry the `eject` command?