# pointerhysteresis parameter not being read in xscrensaver

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, suspend, xscreensaver

I'm trying to disable wake-on-mouse from suspend and not having much success. As an alternative I attempted to increase the pointerhysteresis variable in the Xscreensaver configuration file as others suggested. However, no matter what I set it to it does not appear to make a differenence - the screensaver is still very sensitive to mouse movement and will wake at the tiniest poke.
Does anybody know why this might not be working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse movement wakes computer from suspend how to disable this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/mouse-movement-wakes-computer-from-suspend-how-to-disable-this)

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/741760/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-a-specific-usb-port-so-it-doesnt-accept-any-device
https://askubuntu.com/questions/741760/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-a-specific-usb-port-so-it-doesnt-accept-any-device

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm specifically asking about what can be done to troubleshoot the fact that the pointerhysteresis parameter within the Xscreensaver configuration file doesn't appear to be being read.

I have already read the thread that you linked and successfully implemented it to ignore USB inputs during the suspend state.

Comment: I have two mice, one of them is wireless. While the cabled one is irresponsive of mouse move during sleep, the wireless one wakes up the computer by a single pixel motion. I still don't know what the difference is, but I don't think it has something to do with `pointerHysteresis` value.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Since I was able to successfully disable wake from USB movements, the suspend solution is fine for me. It would be nice if I could also get xscreensaver to work as I wanted to so that I could lock the screen and come back to it when I'm only away from my desk momentarily, but what I have now is a lot better than what I did before.