# Ubuntu 18 command to turn on and off a USB ethernet card

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I have a USB ethernet card that works well with Ubuntu 18.04. Now I need to find a way to turn it on and off with command.

I tried the command `sudo ip l s dev enx00249b450d4d down` (enx00249b450d4d is the name of the interface), but nothing changes.

I also installed net-tools and tried the command `sudo ifconfig enx00249b450d4d down`, but had no luck either.

I searched the internet but the information about Ubuntu 18 is still scarce. Any idea?

Comment: so it's a usb dongle that turns into an ethernet port? would turning off the usb port it's plugged into be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes that solution is also acceptable. Could you provide more details?

Comment: well lets run though theses steps : https://linuxhint.com/list-usb-devices-linux/ start with the first suggested command (`lsusb`) and edit your post to inlcude the output it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like so :

First, run `lsusb`.

The output should be like:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1020  
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0bc2:a013 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:219c Broadcom Corp.
```

In the output, find the device number of the port to be disabled. For example, the Seagate drive in the example has `Device 009` - that is its device number. Then the id will be `usb[device number]` - such as `usb9`

Then, disable USB wake-up (do this only once):

**Be sure to replace `X` in `usbX` with the device number.**

```
echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/wakeup
```

Then turn it off:

```
echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level
```

#### Undo this:

```
echo enabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/wakeup
echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level
```

source :  https://askubuntu.com/a/750455/307184

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried the command `echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/wakeup `, but it returned "No such file or directory disabled"

Comment: do `cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/` and `ls`

Comment: `cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/` and `ls` returns

    1-0:1.0  1-1:1.0  1-2      1-8      1-8:1.1  2-3      usb1
    1-1      1-1:1.1  1-2:1.0  1-8:1.0  2-0:1.0  2-3:1.0  usb2

Comment: see? there is no usb4. I don't know why you got that number but you need to find the right number.