# Can't enable webcam after disabling it

Tags: 18.04, webcam

Tried to disable webcam according this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/750455). After all operations webcam is stop working and I have this output
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qggnq.png)

And after rebooting my machine and changing webcam config to default values
`echo enabled | sudo tee wakeup`
`echo on | sudo tee level`

webcam doesn't work. Even after reboot. And another strange thing that after reboot webcam config values always as on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLROn.png), despite the fact that I changed them before.
Please, help me to figure out what happened

Comment: You seem to be trying to manage USB Port 2, but the output of `lsusb` is showing a Logitech webcam as device 002 on USB Port 1 

Comment: oh. I thought that in *usbX* X - its a device number. Btw if you right why webcam stop working after my manipulations?